# Karaf jdbc - jdbc:query: too many arguments specified

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, apache-karaf

I have a problem with the Karaf jdbc:query command. When I execute the following:

```
karaf@root()> jdbc:query mysql-ds "select * from test"
```

The console always returns:

> Error executing command jdbc:query: too many arguments specified.

Actually, I'm using `Karaf 4.0.9` if this information is useful.

Can you help me?

Comment: Just a hunch...  `jdbc:query "mysql-ds" "select * from test"`

Answer (score 0):

I got it, we need to query without double quotes !

karaf@root()> jdbc:query mysql-ds select * from test

Thank u for your answers :) !